# Incorrect use of the OVER syntax in SqlServer

Tags: sql-server

I have a query to look up the evolution of the number statements, that I have in my statements table. I use following query to loop it

```
SELECT LAST_UPDATED_WEEK, SUM( NUM_STATEMENTS ) OVER (ORDER BY LAST_UPDATED_WEEK ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS "Number of account statements"
    FROM (
      SELECT DATEPART(wk, STATEMENT_CREATION_DATE) AS LAST_UPDATED_WEEK,
             COUNT(DISTINCT STATEMENT_ID) AS NUM_STATEMENTS
      FROM   STATEMENTS_TABLE
      GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, STATEMENT_CREATION_DATE)
```

The purpose of this query is to receive a weekly total number of statements, like underneath:
[image: Table Data]

For example in the week of 31 August, I have 3 new statements. In the week of 7 september I have 4 new statements, which makes the number of statements 7. This for every record in my table

But when I run the query I get following error:

> Error: Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>   SQLState:  S0001
>   ErrorCode: 102

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `) AS t` at the end:

```
SELECT 
    LAST_UPDATED_WEEK, 
    SUM( NUM_STATEMENTS ) OVER (ORDER BY LAST_UPDATED_WEEK ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS 'Number of account statements'
FROM (
    SELECT DATEPART(wk, STATEMENT_CREATION_DATE) AS LAST_UPDATED_WEEK,
            COUNT(DISTINCT STATEMENT_ID) AS NUM_STATEMENTS
    FROM   STATEMENTS_TABLE
    GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, STATEMENT_CREATION_DATE)) AS t
```

Answer (score 0):

You have confused `order by` with `partition by`. The `sum` expression should be:

```
SUM(NUM_STATEMENTS) OVER (PARTITION BY LAST_UPDATED_WEEK 
                          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
                                       CURRENT ROW ) AS 
"Number of account statements"
```

Comment: He is getting weekly cumulative sum, so `PARTITION BY` is not needed here. `SUM() OVER` can be used without `PARTITION BY` on SQL Server 2012  and above.